# PIVOT with Multiple Dates inside "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, in-clause

I have here some problem on inserting multiple dates inside in clause.

Here is the code that I have seen through the internet research.

```
;with cte (datelist, maxdate) as
    (
        select min(arrivaldate) datelist, max(departuredate) maxdate
        from BookingsPerPerson
        union all
        select dateadd(dd, 1, datelist), maxdate
        from cte
        where datelist < maxdate
    ) 
    select c.datelist
    into #tempDates
    from cte c

    select *
    from
    (
        select b.person_id, b.arrivaldate, b.departuredate,
            d.datelist,
            convert(CHAR(10), datelist, 120) PivotDate
        from #tempDates d
        left join BookingsPerPerson b
            on d.datelist between b.arrivaldate and b.departuredate
    ) x
    pivot
    (
        count(datelist)
        for PivotDate in ([2012-01-01], [2012-01-02], [2012-01-03],
                            [2012-01-04], [2012-01-05], [2012-01-06] , [2012-01-07])
    ) p;
```

Since the code is manually adding the dates inside the **IN** clause

```
pivot
    (
        count(datelist)
        for PivotDate in ([2012-01-01], [2012-01-02], [2012-01-03],
                            [2012-01-04], [2012-01-05], [2012-01-06] , [2012-01-07])
    ) p;
```

Can I just use the date which is **extract/split** by this code

```
;with cte (datelist, maxdate) as
        (
            select min(arrivaldate) datelist, max(departuredate) maxdate
            from BookingsPerPerson
            union all
            select dateadd(dd, 1, datelist), maxdate
            from cte
            where datelist < maxdate
        ) 
        select c.datelist
        into #tempDates
        from cte c
```

And use the SELECT statement on the "**IN**" clause inside the pivot statement? 
like this?

```
pivot
        (
            count(datelist)
            for PivotDate in (select c.datelist from #tempDates)
        ) p;
```

I tried this but it gives me an error? 
Is there any way that I can add multiple dates from 
a temporary table and include it inside the **IN** clause?

YOU CAN TRY IT HERE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8857c/9

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. you place first the concatenated dates in one variable..

for example:

**DECLARE @dateArray AS VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @dateArray = '02/01/2014,02/02/2014,02/03/2014,02/04/2014'**

then create a dynamic sql query:
**set @query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE
    PIVOT (count(datelist) PivotDate in (' + @dateArray + '))**

hope it helped you in a way. :)